# Regex - Get all text after pattern from log C#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, logging

I have the following log file that I'd like to parse in C#.

I've gone down the route of using a RegEx to get most of it split.
I've tested this in [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) with MultiLine (m) flag checked.

*Log*

```
5376:0084 2015-08-07 13:51:29.103 Error ### Error Message ###
5376:0084 2015-08-07 13:51:35.545 Error Discarding invalid session
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Verify Session ID failed
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
5376:0084 2015-08-07 13:51:36.013 Error ### Error Message ###
```

Split to Table:

```
| ProcessID | DateTime                | Type  | Message               |
|-----------|-------------------------|-------|-----------------------|
| 5376:0084 | 2015-08-07 13:51:29.103 | Error | ### Error Message ### |
```

I've used the following pattern

```
string pattern = @"(.*:\d{4}) ((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d{3})) ([A-Za-z\n]+) (.*$)";
```

This gets lines 1,3 & 6 but I'd like to gather lines 2-5 into one group.
So **"Discarding ... parameters)"** would be the whole Message.

Comment: Please explain what difference you need in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in log parsing named captures are a great help, I strongly advise to use them. Also, you can have more control over what you capture with `.` using an inline singleline modifier `(?s:...)`. This way, you do not have to use a global `RegexOptions.Singleline` option, and you still can use `.` to match any symbol but a newline.

Here is my attempt:

```
var pattern = @"(?m)^(?<ProcessID>\d{4}:\d{4})\s+(?<DTime>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)\s+(?<Type>\w+)\s+(?<Message>(?s:.*?(?=\n\d+:\d+|\r?\z)))";
```

Here, `(?m)` sets the multiline mode for `^` to match a line start, then I modified the ID and datetime subpatterns for more efficient ones with `\d{n}`, the `Type` part can be actually adjusted to your needs (e.g. `[\w\s]+`), and the `Message` part will only match arbitrary number of characters up to the `XXX:XXXX` on a new line (due to `\n\d+:\d+`) or up to the end of the string (`\z`).
See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3CProcessID%3E%5Cd%7B4%7D%3A%5Cd%7B4%7D)%5Cs%2B(%3F%3CDTime%3E%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D%5Cs%2B%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%2B)%5Cs%2B(%3F%3CType%3E%5Cw%2B)%5Cs%2B(%3F%3CMessage%3E(%3Fs%3A.*%3F(%3F%3D%5Cn%5Cd%2B%3A%5Cd%2B%7C%5Cr%3F%5Cz)))&i=5376%3A0084%202015-08-07%2013%3A51%3A29.103%20Error%20%23%23%23%20Error%20Message%20%23%23%23%0D%0A5376%3A0084%202015-08-07%2013%3A51%3A35.545%20Error%20Discarding%20invalid%20session%0D%0A%20%20%20%20System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException%3A%20Verify%20Session%20ID%20failed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20at%20System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage%20message%2C%20WebResponse%20response%2C%20Stream%20responseStream%2C%20Boolean%20asyncCall)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20at%20System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String%20methodName%2C%20Object%5B%5D%20parameters)%0D%0A5376%3A0084%202015-08-07%2013%3A51%3A36.013%20Error%20%23%23%23%20Error%20Message%20%23%23%23%0D%0A5376%3A0084%202015-08-07%2013%3A51%3A29.103%20Error%20%23%23%23%20Error%20Message%20%23%23%23&o=m), see *Table* tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I love the idea 'named captures', this will give my code more meaning

Answer (score 1):

You need to match also the newline characters which exists at the `Message`
 part. This could be achieved by using DOTALL modifier `s`.

```
@"(?s)(\d+:\d{4}) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}) ([A-Za-z\n]+) (.*?)(?=\n\d+:|$)"
```

or

```
@"(?s)(?:\n|^)(\d+:\d{4}) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}) ([A-Za-z\n]+) (.*?)(?=\n\d+:|$)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sX9vW1/2)

Comment: Thanks, can I just remove Groups 1-10 from Group 0 to get the difference?

Comment: ya, see the demo link. Four capturing groups would be enough.

Comment: There are only 5 groups, indexed from 0 to 4 in a match result with this regex. You cannot remove 10 groups then.

Comment: ya, i excluded the 0th group(which contains all the matched chars).

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Nice joke. 0th group cannot be "excluded", if it were, it would mean a no match. :) Also, there is a `singleline` flag/modifier, not `DOTALL` in C#.

Comment: @stribizhev Don't know what are you talking? Who says 0th group would be removed? What I mean by `I excluded 0th group` is I' talking about the four capturing groups `\(..\)` used in the regex and by default 0th group contains all the atched chars.

Answer (score 0):

Alex. Try this:

```
string pattern = @"^(\S+) (\S+ \S+) (\S+) ((?:.*(?:\n\s)?)+)";
```

(Sample is here: https://regex101.com/r/uI4uQ0/1)

1. (\S+) = "5376:0084";
2. (\S+ \S+) = "2015-08-07 13:51:29.103"
3. (\S+) = "Error" (one word only)
4. ((?:.*(?:\n\s)?)+) = "...session
       System...
       at..."

Magick is here: "\n\s". It says that we need line-break AND any whitespace char.

Good luck, MiKe.

Answer (score 0):

Besides regex, for parsing log file, you have a possibility to use `TextFieldParser` class. Although it is an unnecessary dependance on this assebmly `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`, but it is a good one.

Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2010/05/Do-you-know-the-TextFieldParser.aspx) on how to consume this class.

Comment: This won't help since one of the fields contains newline characters.

Comment: @stribizhev, perhaps using `Environment.NewLine` in the same way as `vbTab` were used here: `reader.Delimiters = New String() {"," , vbTab}`

Comment: From my experience, I could not manage to correctly handle entries with newlines using `TextFieldParser`, I had to perform a thorough pre-process.